# When should tag git a release in Gitlab flow before release or after the release?

Tags: git, gitlab, branching-strategy

We are using Gitlab and Gitlab flow as our branching strategy. We are having `master`, `production` and a bunch of feature branches. Our `master` branch is managing the staging environment and when `master` is merged with `production`, something can be deployed into production. Here is how a developer starts the work:

1. Create a feature branch from `master`
2. Create a WIP merge request from the feature to `master`
3. Start implementing stuff. Colleagues can see the changes on the fly and can help to have the review as early as possible
4. Our code quality gate also verifies the commits while the MR is running
5. Remove the WIP prefix when the development is finished and verified locally
6. When the review is finished and MR got approved, it will be merged into master
7. A CI/CD release pipeline will be initiated to run different tests and at the end deploy the image into staging

The problem is if I set the tag release to be applied at the start of the release pipeline, then some jobs may fail to be deployed to the staging and it can create a release tag on git that doesn't end up to be deployed in the staging environment. In this case, some versions will be skipped. However, if I set the tag release as late as possible like after the release is deployed on the staging environment (or even production), then the CI/CD job won't work as expected as the CI/CD job is triggered if a new release is initiated (detect any changes on the VERSION file).

I was wondering if it is very unusual to have lots of release tags, but only a few of them are end up to be deployed to the `staging` or `production`? The only thing I can see is this approach will create some noises when it comes to the git tag. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you clarify how some versions will be skipped? Have you consider using git tags for the branches? You can also also consider using [only/if condition](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic) for this use case.

Comment: @ArihantGodha If I set the git tag at the start of the no.7 then if the cicd job fails that version will not get deployed into the staging environment. Now a developer takes a look at the pipeline and finds out that the test was failed. Then, he/she should create a new release (patch) with the fix and create a new MR. Now if the CICD pipeline succeeds, the new version will be only deployed into the staging, and the previous version won't get deployed anywhere and literally skipped. Regarding the only/except scenario, that is what is being used on the VERSION file to trigger the pipeline.

Comment: "However, if I set the tag release as late as possible like after the release is deployed on the staging environment (or even production), then the CI/CD job won't work as expected as the CI/CD job is triggered if a new release is initiated (detect any changes on the VERSION file)" - I don't understand this. If the CI/CD fails then the dev will need to make a patch. This patched version is a NEW version, so doesn't that include a change to VERSION to indicate that a new release is ready?

Comment: @Vlad274 Yes, that's right. What I am saying is we have got a version that is useless (v1.1.0) and would not have any use-case (Because that version is broken and could not pass the pipeline). The fix should come as a new version (v1.1.1).